# What does the "v3-1683361313937-9205711099327" mean in Web Vitals INP GA report?

Tags: google-analytics, core-web-vitals, web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

My web page has a very poor field INP score, but I can't reproduce the poor INP via web vitals extension or devtools on my own. So the best attempt is to use [web vitals JS SDK](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) to collect real user data and send the data to GA.

However, when I checked the GA reports, it's all like this:

What is this? How can I locate the problem with all the v3-xxxxx labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a unique id for that event. It allows the event value to be overwritten if a later INP event comes in with a higher value. Other than that, knowing the actual value is not really useful to a user.

What is more useful, is logging the `event_target` available with the attribution build. This will show you the element clicked on (the button, or whatever) which should help you track down the slow event. See [this post](https://web.dev/debug-performance-in-the-field/#usage-with-the-web-vitals-javascript-library) on how to log that.

I see you are using Universal Analytics, so you can use the [Web Vitals Report](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-vitals-report) to extract the target if you're already sending it to GA and display it a nice tool. Do be aware that UA is due to be switched off soon however and Web Vitals Report is not compatible with GA4.

Also be aware, that INP is a tricky metric to optimise for. Quite often a slow interaction can be due to the main thread just being busy with previous interactions. So the event you're looking at may not actually be that slow, and just be a victim of a generally overworked website.

We also [recently updated the Web Vitals extension to log more data](https://web.dev/debug-cwvs-with-web-vitals-extension/) to help you identify slow interactions which may be another way to help find the issues on your website.

Comment: Thanks Barry, I have updated the extension and the INP log works great.